# Copy files from folders and sub folders without preserving directory structure

Tags: linux, file-copy

I have a folder(A) which is structured like this

```
          Main Directory(A)
               |
               |
Subdir------Subdir2-----Subdir3
  |           |            |
  |           |            |
f0--f1      f0--f1       f0--f1
```

I want to copy and paste all files(recursively) in A to a new directory B. BUT I don't want to preserve the directory structure,i.e all files in A should be in B without any children directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, in a shell :

```
$ find A -type f -exec cp {} B \;
```

Comment: Depending how many files you have there may be a noticeable performance gain by using the '+;' ending argument instead of '\;'

Comment: If his version of find support it

Comment: Man you are fast Gilles!

Comment: You should be aware that when two of your files have same names (e.g. `f0--f1`) the last one being copied will be the only one left.

Comment: @GillesQuenot It's at least standard syntax, so if it's not a _really ancient_ implementation of `find`, it will support `-exec ... {} +`.  The real issue with that is that you would have to use GNU `cp`: `-exec cp -t B {} +` (the `{}` has to be last, just before the `+`), but since this is Linux, that should not be an issue.